# Detect a cutout/semicircle in an image

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing

Below is a binary image in which I would like to detect the "hills", semicircles, cutouts.. In the image below in the red circle. The detection does not have to be precise, I just need to know that something like this is in the picture. I am thinking about the algorithm which would use kind of line sweep approach and count the black pixels on the line and evaluate that with some kind of "cleveristic", but before that I would like to know if I am missing any technique that would be easier or more robust. I have tried the HoughCircles, but with no good results, because the circles have quite huge radius and there is many of them (houghCircles takes grayscale image as input).

[image: Binary]

Comment: I don't know where you are from, but where I come from, semi-circles look different ;)

Comment: Can you be more specific about what information you want to extract ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust  as you have guessed yourself it is a defect detection. I do not need the exact characteristics. I just need to find out if there is an defect in otherwise nice rectangular shape.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Counting pixels should be fine in this simple situation. If you face more complex scenarios with other things you don't want to count in, you should consider a blob detector.
This method searches for regions of connected pixels. Once you have blobs you can easily sort them by size, shape, position which helps to get rid of unwanted things.

https://www.learnopencv.com/blob-detection-using-opencv-python-c/

This is a very basic technique. Please read a book on image processing fundamentals befor you continue. It will make life much easier.

Comment: Basically what you re suggesting is to find contours and look for the area? I wanted to avoid that.

Comment: @Croolman: if you are after a geometric characteristic such as a radius of curvature, it will be hard to achieve this without looking at... the shape (hence the contour).

Comment: @Croolman you don't have to, but if you have to somehow characterize those black regions as you maybe have to filter out things that you are not interested in, you can't avoid it. if you just want to know if something is there or not, counting pixels is sufficient.

Answer (score 1):

As @piglet said, this is a case of blob analysis.

If you want to further characterize and classify the defects, you have to compute some geometrical features of the shapes such as area, diameter, elungation... and feed them to a classifier/neural net.